# Rabbit took a sharp downturn after starting new antibiotics

Tags: health, rabbits, medicines

We took our rabbit in a week ago because she wasn't eating much, and the vet said she had an infection in her cheek because of tooth problems which she has had for years now. They sent us home with antibiotics after clipping the offending teeth. But the eating problems didn't seem to get better, so yesterday we took her back, and they did a blood test. The vet concluded that it was a gallbladder infection and gave us new antibiotics, along with probiotics.

But after starting her on the antibiotics, she stopped eating entirely. She seems weaker (her paws are more 'slidy' than usual) and I've noticed a bit of swelling on the bottom of her left rib cage. Due to Tomb Sweeping Day, we won't be able to see even the emergency vet for at least 36 hours.

**Is this a normal response to antibiotics, or something we should worry about?**

Comment: What antibiotics is being used?  See these two related questions. [What antibiotics should not be given to a rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/5736/13) & [What antibiotics are generally safe for rabbits?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/5734/13)

Answer (score 2):

Stopping to eat is a very important sign for you as rabbit owner. If your rabbit do not eat for approximately 24 hours it is lost. The digestive systems of rabbits are not made for non eating periods of more than 24 hours.

You have to do first aid to encourage your bunny to eat. Look this question for first aid advise: [First aid kit for rabbits](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/what-should-be-in-a-rabbit-first-aid-kit).

**So first: get your bunny to eat**

Tooth problems are a very hard problem in bunnies. The vet has to do a x-ray to see all, because the body of rabbits is build in a way, the vet could not see all teeth and mouth parts through the open mouth. 
Cutting teeth is a risk too. Because of the high pressure in cutting the teeth will splinter and get cracks. This opens the doors wide for any infections. If any, the teeth should be shortened by grinding.

Tooth infections could easy reach the blood cycle, so the infection causing bacteria could reach all other organs. Maybe this could make the connection to the gall bladder.

More to write will be more and more speculation and only a rabbit experienced vet could help you here.

At the close again: make your bunny eating! Try all "sweets" your bunny likes and if this not helps use something to grind hay into "hay dust" and wet it. This pulp you feed the rabbit with the backside of a spoon or a injection kit (clearly without needle).

Please write again, how your bunny is going.

Comment: We're using critical care (hay dust) to ensure that she gets some food in her, and we've found a vet to see her in a few hours.

Comment: I wish you all the best. Because if one do not have "critical care" it is faster to make hay dust as first aid and then buy it. Good that you have some at home!